# Viability of using ADF Faces outside of jDeveloper studio

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

Having worked with 2 JSF component libraries, or frameworks if you wish, I can't help
but wonder if I'm missing a trick by not evaluating ADF Faces. The big stumbling block
for me is the way ADF is clearly deliberately tied in with jDeveloper studio. I work
with NetBeans on a glassfish a/s, and as open as I am to change, I want to maximise
my existing experience and leverage this stability.

My (tentative) rationale is that perhaps a company with the resources of Oracle could,
perhaps, come up with a better quality product than other alternatives and with superior
functionality, and this is what I wish to evaluate.

So I just wondered if anyone had any experience they could share with respect to working
with ADF Faces outside a jDeveloper environment. Presumably from a technical perspective
it's not much more than extracting the necessary jars from the distribution and taking
it from there. Equally important would be any licensing/legal considerations of course.
I've read that ADF has a business layer however I'd want to continue working with a Java
6 EE stack at this time.

What would be really cool would be to have a maven repository, although presumably the
reason that no such thing exists is to protect the jDeveloper business.

1. Has anyone got ADF working outside jDeveloper, got it working and can provide a small
   amount of direction as to any major considerations.
2. If so, is it worth it? is ADF Faces a superior and more in depth product than can
   otherwise be found (oh no, what have I said...)?
3. What are the licensing considerations? my present understanding is that fees would be
   payable is you're not using weblogic. How about glassfish enterprise?
4. I have only recently found out, and was very surprised, to realise that ADF has the
   third JSF core implementation, alongside Mojarrra and MyFaces. Is this just a case of
   taking the RI and making a few necessary changes to support core ADF functionality or
   more than that? I see from the JIRA that Ed Burns corresponds closely with the ADF
   team, of course they now work for the same company. Clearly the RI has to mirror the
   spec, and that takes time, so this in itself could be interesting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

dont know if this will help you , but it seems that you can now freely deploy adf on glassfish server

https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/admin.111230/e16179/ap_glassfish.htm#BABIEADD

Answer (score 0):

ADF is only officially [certified](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/jdev11gr2-cert-405181.html) to work with WebSphere 7.0.0.13 AS or ND(aside from weblogic of course). Although there are blogs and forum posts that indicate people were able to make it work with Tomcat(with much pain of course).

I know for a fact that there is an [eclipse](http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_faces_now_in_eclipse) version/plugin/whatever that has ADF Faces features.

AFAIK, you only have to pay when you are using a container/AS that is not weblogic.

ADF Faces is great. It has all the components you would expect plus more. It also has a great Controller framework(see ADF Task Flows). For demos you can check out the [Demo](http://rea.oracle.com/riams/faces/index.jspx;).